# Embedd font in RichEditableText

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am using RichEditableText of flex, and i want to embed my own font in RichEditableText , so i gave fontLookUp=EMBEDD_CFF, still it is not taking my embedded fonts, and how to use text flow with this RichEditableText.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the following code for using embedded font with RichEditableText.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo">
<s:layout>
    <s:BasicLayout />
</s:layout>

<fx:Style>
    @namespace s "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark";
    @namespace mx "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/halo";

    @font-face {
        src: url("assets/ACaslonPro-Regular.otf");
        fontFamily: "ACaslonProRegularEmbedded";
        embedAsCFF: true;
    }

    s|RichEditableText {
        fontFamily: ACaslonProRegularEmbedded;
        fontLookup: embeddedCFF;
        fontSize: 34;
    }
</fx:Style>

<s:RichEditableText id="textView"
                    text="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. 01234567890"
                    width="400"
                    horizontalCenter="0"
                    verticalCenter="0" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks you sumit, but i am using a font swf which is created in cs5,i have to embed that swfs in RichEditableText. and i gave textLayoutFormat.fontLookup = FontLookup.EMBEDDED_CFF too,still it's not taking my embedd fonts

Comment: Can you share the font swf so that I can test it?

Comment: You can extract the font from the swf using  swfextract http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Swfextract